# How to copy a data validation formula from a single cell to a row

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I copy a data validation formula from a single cell to a row;
let's say from A1 to A2:A500, while the formula inside of the data validation should be adjusted according to its cell location.

For example, if the formula in A1 is `SUM($B$1,$C$1)` then in A2 the formula should be adjusted to `SUM($B$2,$C$2)`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm assuming this is MS Excel, so, what did you try so far?

Comment: By the way,  `A2:A500` is a *column,* not a row.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change [absolute to relative references](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9):

1. select the range you want to apply conditional format to (A2:A500)
2. create a new conditional format
3. enter formula `SUM(B2,C2)`
   *(note the lack of `$` signs)*